# Xamarin Android AccountPicker how to get result (Closed)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do i get the result of the choosen account from my AccountPicker
i tried to use the code below with no succes.

Im new to xamarin.

Does someone has any ideas.
ofc i have the required permission: `GET_ACCOUNTS`

```
Activity ac = ((Activity)Forms.Context);

Intent intent = AccountPicker.NewChooseAccountIntent(null, AccountManager.Get(ac).GetAccounts(), new String[] { "com.google" }, false, null, null, null, null);

ac.StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);

// I tried 
var accountName = intent.GetStringExtra(AccountManager.KeyAccounts);
```

Note this is inside an Dependency Service Class.

Comment: Just like you would in Android, override the `OnActivityResult` method in your activity (for more info read here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: Can i use the OnActivtiyResult in any class ??

Comment: I did say in your activity..and for that matter fragment.

Comment: I  have none since im working in Xamarin.Forms with dependecy services

Comment: Ahh, might want to add that tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
Its not on the radar anymoire